# Chrome 38 Update broke the "use system title bar and boarders"

Tags: updates, google-chrome, titlebar

I can't get rid of the blue bar it was brown before the update for chrome.

[image]

any ideas or fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go chrome://settings and press button "Use GTK+ theme"

[image]